# Passing type to react component declared with arrow function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

There is something I can't figure out with the passed type for the React component.

### Problem

Parent component:

```js
import React from "react";
import ChildrenComponent from './ChildrenComponent'

type TParentComponent = {
    // no matter what here
}

const ParentComponent:React.FC<TParentComponent> = props => {

    type TTypeInParentComponent = 'special type I can declare only inside ParentComponent'
    type TChildrenComponent = {
        childrenComponentProp: TTypeInParentComponent
    }

    return (
        <ChildrenComponent<TChildrenComponent> /* error: TS2558: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1. */> 
            Something
        </ChildrenComponent>
    )
}

export default ParentComponent
```

Children component:

```js
import React from "react";

type TChildren = {
 // how to pass the "TChildrenComponent" type from the ParentComponent here?
}

const ChildrenComponent:React.FC<TChildren> = props => {

    const { childrenComponentProp } = props /* error: TS2339: Property 'childrenComponentProp' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'. */

    return (
        <div>
            Something else
        </div>
    )
}

export default ChildrenComponent
```

**Question: how to pass type TChildrenComponent from ParentComponent to ChildrenComponent?**

---

### Update 2021

After some time, I still did not find an answer to my question. But I want to leave some explanation here.

Example:

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {

    // yes, exactly INSIDE the component. not ouside with "export type ..."
    type TChildrenComponentSpecialType = string

    return (
        //                 ↓↓↓ here we pass the type to children component
        <ChildrenComponent<TChildrenComponentSpecialType>
            specialParam='no matter what'
        />
    );
};
```

This is how we can do with component declared with a simple function like "function Component() {}"

```js
//                        ↓↓↓ here we get it                ↓↓↓ here we pass it to children component's type
function ChildrenComponent<T>(props: TChildrenComponentProps<T>):JSX.Element {

    const { specialParam } = props;

    return (
        <div>no matter what is here</div>
    );
};
```

But I haven't found how to do this with a component declared with an arrow function.
We can't do like this:

```js
const ChildrenComponent = <T>(props: TChildrenComponentProps<T>):JSX.Element => {

    const { specialParam } = props;

    return (
        <div>no matter what is here</div>
    );
};
```

---

### Update 2022

1.In examples above I tried to do something like this:

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {

    // yes, exactly INSIDE the component. not ouside with "export type ..."
    type TChildrenComponentSpecialType = string

    return (
        //                 ↓↓↓ here we pass the type to children component
        <ChildrenComponent<TChildrenComponentSpecialType>
            specialParam='no matter what'
        />
    );
};
```

Now I'm convinced that despite the ability to do this in typescript, we shouldn't do this. If we are sure that we need to do just that - we can be sure that we are doing something wrong.

2. We can do something like that:

```js
type TComponent<T> = {
  items: T[];
}

export const Component = <T extends unknown>(props: TComponent<T>) => {
  /* ... */
}
```

But you can understand that it doesn't do anything useful for us.
Furthermore, [eslint has a rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unnecessary-type-constraint.md) for this.

P.S. What I don't understand here is why eslint in the [examples](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unnecessary-type-constraint.md#-correct) says this:

```js
/* ... */

/*           ↓↓↓  if i do something like this my IDE will yell at me   */
const Quux = <T>() => {};

/*           ↓↓↓  but this variant works good   */
function Quuz<T>() {}
```

> Maybe it depends on `tsconfig.json` ???

Comment: Your `TChildren` type is not generic. It should be defined like `type TChildren<MyGeneric> = { arg: MyGeneric[] }`.

Comment: @Noah May, Problem is not here. I know how to pass to type. The question is not about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `TTypeInParentComponent` outside the parent component.

```
export type TTypeInParentComponent = ...
```

and in the Child component, you import this type:

```
import { TTypeInParentComponent } from "path to parent"
```

Comment: Thanks. But i want to declare special type INSIDE parent component. Not outside.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ChildrenComponent` is not currently a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), so it doesn't make sense to use it like `ChildrenComponent<T...>`. You could do this for example:

```
const ChildrenComponent = <T>(props) => {
    ...
}
```

or

```
function ChildrenComponent<T>(props) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I understand this concept. I mean, is it posible to use `:React.FC` and make this component generic ? Something like `const Component: React.FC<SomeType> = <TypeFromParent>(props) => ...` ?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to use React.FC because it is defined as a non-generic function — but why do you need it? You should be able to omit the explicit type annotation and TypeScript will infer the types.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass a type explicitly if your child props are generically typed.

```js
type ChildProps<typePassedFromParent = any> = {
    singleOne: typePassedFromParent;
    array: typePassedFromParent[];
}

const Child: React.FC<ChildProps> = (props) => {
    const { singleOne, array } = props;
    // ...
}
```

```js
const Parent: React.FC = () => {
    const childProp = [1, 2, 3];

    return <Child
        array={childProp}
        singleOne="This gives an error since childProp is an \
            array of numbers and this is a string"
        />;
}
```

If you need to override the type of a child prop, you can do it with coercion:

```js
<Child array={myArray as number[]} />
```